# Nested Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

can someone please let me know, whats wrong with the format of my nested loop. i dont seem to be getting it to loop correctly. the values that are the same are not being generated together.

```
for (var field in Itemlist) {
        for (var field in EstItems){
            console.log(Itemlist[field].item_id, EstItems[field].zoho_id);
            if (EstItems[field].zoho_id == Itemlist[field].item_id) {
                console.log("We are In");
                var id = EstItems[field].itemID;
                var itemID = EstItems[field].zoho_id;
                var barcode = EstItems[field].barcode;
                //var EstBarcode = EstItems[field].itemID;
                var description = EstItems[field].description;
                var cost = EstItems[field].cost;
                var shippingCost = "500";
                var clearingCharges = "";
                var quantityOrdered = 1;
                //var quantityRecvd = EstItems[field].itemID;
                //var quantityRTD = EstItems[field].itemID;
                var selected = 0;
                var totalcost = (cost*quantityOrdered)+parseFloat(shippingCost);
                var categoryID = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Variable name `field` is used twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem introduced by overwriting a previous variable.

```
for (var field in Itemlist) {
  // `field` here is a property from ItemList
  for (var field in EstItems){
    // `field` here is a property from EstItems
    // Any attempt to access the `field` var from the outer loop will fail, as it has been overwritten.
  }
}
```

Rename `field` for either loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Guys. Don't know how I missed that